# I can't change picker title color for iOS in maui

Tags: .net, maui

I tried to change picker title color in maui. but i can see still it's white color.

here is my code:

```
 <commonviews:TPicker SelectedIndexChanged="NextButton_Clicked" Margin="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAction}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource 00dp}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding ActionList}" FontSize="15"  Title="Action" TitleColor="{StaticResource TGreen}" 
                                                      TextColor="{StaticResource WhiteColor}">
 </commonviews:TPicker>
```

even tried to change from platform handler.

```
     handler.PlatformView.AttributedPlaceholder = new Foundation.NSAttributedString(handler.PlatformView.AttributedPlaceholder.Value, foregroundColor: UIKit.UIColor.Gray);
```

Comment: I reproduce this issue. TitleColor property works in Xamarin Forms but fails in Maui. You could raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues)

Answer (score 0):

First set `handler.PlatformView.Text` to `null`;

```cs
handler.PlatformView.Text = null;
```

Then this should work;

```cs
handler.PlatformView.AttributedPlaceholder = new Foundation.NSAttributedString(handler.PlatformView.AttributedPlaceholder.Value, foregroundColor: UIKit.UIColor.Gray);
```